# OnActivityResult does not work inside fragment. How can I fix this on my code?

Tags: java, android, onactivityresult

So I am coding this app that needs to pick a profile picture from the phone, crop, compress and save the picture to a custom location in the internal memory and also set the compressed bitmap as a preview in a circular imageview. All this inside a fragment. But my onActivityResult is not called at all inside the fragment.

Here is my code:

***ViewPagerAdapter.class***

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
                return new ConfigurationFragment1();
            case 1:
                return new ConfigurationFragment2();
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

***ConfigurationFragment2.class***

```
public class ConfigurationFragment2 extends Fragment {

    CircularImageView profilePicker;
    EditText user1NameInput;
    Uri profileImageURI;
    Bitmap compressedImageFile;
    Boolean profileImageSet = false;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_configuration_2, container, false);

        profilePicker = rootView.findViewById(R.id.configuration_profile_picker);
        user1NameInput = rootView.findViewById(R.id.configuration_name_1);

        profilePicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                }
                else if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                }
                else {
                    chooseProfilePicture();
                }
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

    public void chooseProfilePicture(){
        CropImage.activity().setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON).setAspectRatio(1,1).start(getActivity());
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE)
        {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
            {
                assert result != null;
                profileImageURI = result.getUri();
                File thumbnailURI = new File(Objects.requireNonNull(profileImageURI.getPath()));
                try
                {
                    compressedImageFile = new Compressor(getActivity())
                            .setMaxHeight(500)
                            .setMaxWidth(500)
                            .setQuality(100)
                            .compressToBitmap(thumbnailURI);
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                profilePicker.setImageBitmap(compressedImageFile);
                String profilePictureFolder = "/com.testapp.app/";
                String profilePictureUser1Name = "profilePicUser1.jpg";
                String profilePictureUser1Path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + profilePictureFolder + profilePictureUser1Name;
                File imagePath = new File(profilePictureUser1Path);
                FileOutputStream fos;

                try {
                    if (!imagePath.exists()) {
                        File wallpaperDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + profilePictureFolder);
                        wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
                    }
                    File file = new File(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + profilePictureFolder), profilePictureUser1Name);
                    if (file.exists()) {
                        file.delete();
                    }
                    fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
                    compressedImageFile.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fos);
                    fos.flush();
                    fos.close();
                    profileImageSet = true;
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    Log.e("eRROR", e.getMessage(), e);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            else if(resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE)
            {
                assert result != null;
                Exception error = result.getError();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and ***MainActivity.class***

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_configuration);
        setTheme(R.style.AppThemeBlueStatusDarkText);
        objectInstance();

        viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
        viewPager.setSwipeable(false);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage);
}

 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

The onActivityResult code works flawlessly in a normal activity, but not in this fragment. How exactly can I solve my issue? Thank you!

Comment: Issue is with this weird `CropImage` library. You have to use `Fragment.startActivityForResult` but that library is probably using `Activity.startActivityForResult` so it's not properly forwarded down to fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is here:

> ```
> public void chooseProfilePicture(){
>     CropImage.activity().setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON).setAspectRatio(1,1).start(getActivity());
> }
> ```

The [source code for this library](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper/blob/master/cropper/src/main/java/com/theartofdev/edmodo/cropper/CropImage.java) shows the following:

> ```
> public void start(@NonNull Activity activity) {
>   mOptions.validate();
>   activity.startActivityForResult(getIntent(activity), CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
> }
> ```

This means that the `Activity` argument to the `start()` method is going to be used to start the CropImage activity, and therefore will be the place that receives the result. Instead, you should use this other `start()` method that the library exposes:

> ```
> public void start(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Fragment fragment) {
>   fragment.startActivityForResult(getIntent(context), CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
> }
> ```

That means that you'd use this code:

```
public void chooseProfilePicture(){
    CropImage.activity().setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON).setAspectRatio(1,1).start(getActivity(), this);
}
```

And now the result should be delivered to your Fragment.

Comment: Damn, it really was as simple as that. I have to learn how to look in the documentation of the libraries I use, but I thought it was something more complicated than that. Thank you so much, man.

Comment: No worries. Happy hunting!

Answer (score 0):

```
 firstly you need to add tag to fragment ConfigurationFragment2 when initilaize it the edit onActivityResult in your activity like this :

@Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_configuration);
            setTheme(R.style.AppThemeBlueStatusDarkText);
            objectInstance();

            viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
            viewPager.setSwipeable(false);
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage);
    }

     @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            Fragment ConfigurationFragment2 = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("ConfigurationFragment2 Tag");
    switch (requestCode) {
                case  CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE:
    if (ConfigurationFragment2 != null)
                        ConfigurationFragment2.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                    break;

    }

        }
```